# Null Pointer Exception when calling method from object

Tags: java, arrays

I get a `NullPointerException` when I run this. It occurs on the line `listings[i].input();`

Am I declaring this right? I want an array of 3 listing objects, input to them with my `input()` method, then output in reverse order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Listing[] listings = new Listing[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
        listings[i].input();
    }

    for (int i = listings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(listings[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't construct the individual `Listing` objects. So `listings[0] == null`. This is true for all elements of the array - they're all initialized to `null` by default.

You must first say `listings[i] = new Listing()` or the like, before your `listings[i].input()`.

Comment: Don't forget that you can also initialize the array with the syntax: Listing[] listings = new Listing[] {new Listing(), new Listing(), new Listing()}

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you'll have to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listings.length; i++)
{
    listings[i] = new Listing();
    listings[i].input();
}
```